The Video size is puzzling when I use Android MediaRecorder to record webm video with VP8
I use Android MediaRecorder to record a video, the video size is normal when using H264 and H265, but abnormal when change to webm with VP8, for example 480P, the h264 is 480 x 720, but vp8 is 720 x 480, then the video change oritation.
Who can tell me how can I fix it......  thanks
CamcorderProfile mProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mProfile.videoFrameWidth, mProfile.videoFrameHeight);
mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

I change setOrientationHint,it not work.
